# c# program using dll not compatible with windows 7

Tags: c#, dll

I have this visual studio c# program that uses a dll file. The project works on windows xp, but it is not compatible with windows 7.Just for information i use dll as a reference to my project

-I have tried changing the build settings.(Any PC/x64/x86) 
-I have tried using it on windows 32 bit pc
- I have tried running the exe file by changing compatibility properties

The dll file is not compatible with the processor it says, when i change the build settings(target platform to x64)

What should be my next step?

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: So you've got a 32-bit DLL that you're trying to execute within a 64-bit process?  Is this a 3rd party DLL or can you build a 64-bit version?

Comment: Find a different, compatible, DLL that will work on all of your platforms?

Comment: @D Stanley : Yes and I can not build, cause i have no idea about dll files... this is someone else's project whom i can't contact

Comment: @JustinNiessner : If I only knew how to i would have done that i would try finding a better solution than getting into that.

Answer (score 0):

There's a very good chance that your EXE is being compiled AnyCPU and the .DLL is specifically marked x86 only. This will cause a reject on 64 bit machines. This often gets reported as incompatible with Windows Vista or Windows 7.

We had an engineer here who tried marking an intermediate DLL as x86 and another intermediate as AnyCpu before targeting the final dll. This doesn't work at all. The only solution is to change the EXE to x86.

Please note the dill file is not compatible with the procesor is not quoted, but if anything like that, it won't work.

Comment: Warning 1 Assembly generation -- Referenced assembly '***************.dll' targets a different processor
Thats what I get when i change the platform target to x64.

Comment: You have an x86 only .DLL for sure then. Change your target for .EXE to x86.

Comment: it was x86 previously but it didn't seem to work on windows 7.I tried it on win 7 (32 and 64 bit)

Comment: Hey, I used the dependency walker(64 bit) and This was what i got "Error: At least one required implicit or forwarded dependency was not found.
Error: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in an implicitly dependent module.
Error: Modules with different CPU types were found.
Warning: At least one delay-load dependency module was not found.
Warning: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in a delay-load dependent module."

Comment: Ok then. So you reported the error that indicates bitness problem, but changing the bitness yields a different error. What is the error on Win7 32 bit?

Comment: Then changing your .EXE project to x86 specific will fix the problem.

Comment: It just stops working...when i run the build... while debugging it says dll is not compatible with 64 bit

Comment: Then you did not change your .EXE to 32 bit specific. If you do not believe me, go try on Windows XP 64 bit.